# How do I check if the incoming message edited in Telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I use Telethon to create Telegram Client using Python just to fetch media and messages from a specific Telegram Channel. It work really well like this :

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print("============================")
    msg_id = event.id
    texts = event.text
    raw_text = texts.replace('[','[')
    file_name = str(msg_id) + '.tlmsg'
    if event.photo:
        media_name = "media/" + str(msg_id) + '.jpg'
        print("Media saved on",media_name)
        await event.download_media(media_name)
    print(raw_text)
    f = open("message/"+file_name, "w",encoding="utf-8")
    f.write(raw_text)
    f.close()
```

but every once in a while, the Telegram Channel edit one of their message.

How do I get the edited message from that channel?

I search all over the internet but all I saw its just to edit the actual message itself, not fetching the edited message FROM someone else

Comment: As far as I know, you will need to fetch the messages again to see the edited messages

Answer (score 0):

I was creating a application in python, which does the same as yours, and i ended up facing the same problem. I found in the telethon documentation, that besides NewMessage, events has MessageEdited also. If you see in the official documentation for telethon, in the 2.8.2 section, pag. 25 says "Occurs whenever a message is edited. Just like NewMessage, you should treat this event as a Message.
Full documentation for the MessageEdited.", i.e, whenever a message is edited, this event occurs and you can retrieve all the information about the message. Here is the link for this documetation: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/telethon/stable/telethon.pdf. With me it worked, just take a look of a functional example:

```
@client.on(events.MessageEdited(chats='channel'))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.id)
    print(event.text)
```

In the parameters of MessageEdited you can pass from which channel you will be waiting for this event. It works whenever any message from the channel you specify is edited. If you don't pass any parameter, the function you define will be triggered whenever any message in any dialogue is edited.